# function for eeprom searching

Tags: c, search, logic, mplab-c18

I have an array stored in EEPROM

Starting with {0,0,0,0,1,1,1...} up to 54 elements from address '0'-address'53' and i have cross checked the value and everything is fine.

but when i employ a 'search function' and i have passed '0' as the argument as it searches from 0th address.

unsigned char search(char current_time)

```
                    {
                        unsigned int    loopcnt = 0;
                        unsigned int   add ;
                        unsigned char   addr = 0;          //We will store start address of 1's here
                        unsigned char lastAddr =current_time;
                                            unsigned int x;
                    add = 0;
                              //If lastAddr is already overflowing, reset it
            if(lastAddr >= 53)
            {
                    lastAddr = 0;
                    addr=53;
                    return(addr);
            }

                    for(loopcnt = lastAddr; loopcnt < 54; loopcnt++)
                {

                    addr = loopcnt;
                                    x=eeread(add);
                                    //This is start location of our scanning
                                        while(x!= 0)
                            {
                                        x=eeread(add);
                    loopcnt++;
                                             add++;
                    //Count the 1's we got!
                    if(loopcnt==53)
                    {
                        addr=53;
                        break;
                    }
                }


                }

                    return (addr);

            }
```

But it has to return '4' as value since after the '4'th element is non zero.

> But it returns 53 always.

Why is it like that?

Im using c18 compiler..If there is any mistake in logic do correct me.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above code it the break only breaks out of the while loop, so the while loop will break when x is non-zero, however the for-loop that is encasing it will increment and continue anyway, breaking only when loopcnt is 54 (above 53) at which point addr will always be 53.